# OpenCV: Allcoate memory in GPU using OpenCL

Tags: opencv, opencl

I have seen sample OCL examples, where I create buffer using oclMat. But I want to allocate memory in GPU directly using clCreateBuffer(). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

Use clCreateBuffer with appropriate flags and use the buffer accordingly on the device.

Do check for the error on API.

Comment: I tried using it inside main() in OCL square example and it says identifier clCreateBuffer is undefined. why it is so ? I see ocl.hpp is include, but this also have no such functions but only oclMat

Comment: I guess this is linking issue, if you are on linux follow this tutorial http://www.thebigblob.com/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/ a if on win google it.

Comment: solved after I included this:   #include <opencv2\ocl\cl_runtime\cl_runtime_opencl.hpp>